# Timer Picker in Flutter with Localization

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I'm making an app in Flutter. I want to use Cupertino Timer Picker but when I use localization timer picker doesn't work in other languages. It seems it only works in English. How can I use Cupertino Timer Picker in other languages? This is my current code for timer picker.

```
void _buildTimePicker(BuildContext context) {
showCupertinoModalPopup<void>(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return _buildBottomPicker(
      CupertinoTimerPicker(
        mode: CupertinoTimerPickerMode.ms,
        initialTimerDuration: timer,
        onTimerDurationChanged: (Duration newTimer) {
          setState(() => timer = newTimer);
        },
      ),
    );
  },
);}
Widget _buildBottomPicker(Widget picker) {
return Container(
  height: 216.0,
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 6.0),
  color: CupertinoColors.white,
  child: DefaultTextStyle(
    style: const TextStyle(
      color: CupertinoColors.black,
      fontSize: 22.0,
    ),
    child: GestureDetector(
      // Blocks taps from propagating to the modal sheet and popping.
      onTap: () {},
      child: SafeArea(
        top: false,
        child: picker,
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}